# How to save a string in a Liststring in flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hello I don't find a solution to add a string in a liststring that I can save with shardpref.

I have a specific case where I use QR code reader, the output is a string that I want to store in a Liststring and save with sharedpref

Here is the part of the plugin who generate the String code of the QRcode:

```
 void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
    final channel = controller.channel;
    controller.init(qrKey);
    this.controller = controller;
    channel.setMethodCallHandler((MethodCall call) async {
      switch (call.method) {
        case "onRecognizeQR":
          dynamic arguments = call.arguments;
          setState(() {

            qrText = arguments.toString();
```

qrText is a String. I tried to change argments.toListstring(); but I have no output when I did this ...

Here is my save List function where I can't add qrText to the Stringlist

```
 save_code() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {

      prefs.setStringList("save_code",qrText); // qrText need to be a Stringlist
      _my_save_code_list = prefs.getStringList("save_code");

    } );
  }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to use a StringList? If it is only the code you could also save it as a normal string, right? Or is the string too long to be a normal string?

-> I think you need to do it like this:

```
save_code() async {
SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
List<String> stringList = [];
stringList.add(qrText);

setState(() {

  prefs.setStringList("save_code",stringList); // qrText need to be a Stringlist
  _my_save_code_list = prefs.getStringList("save_code");

} );


}
```

Comment: Thank you exactly what I want :) I need list because I save all Qrcode generated and read if QRcode have already been saved.

Comment: This still would be the same for a 'prefs.setString('save_code')' so you don't have to put the String into a List<String>, right? You can call prefs.getString('save_code') too.